# Identifying nan values for a variable

Tags: python

I am running a `linregress` regression and creating a statistic.  Please see the following snippet of code:

```
X = dfMyRoll.ix[1:,'SCORE']
Y = dfMyRoll.ix[1:,'SCORE_LAG']

slope,intercept,_,_,stderr=linregress(X,Y)

tStatistic = slope/stderr
```

Sometimes the output for the tStatistic returns a `nan` value.  Could someone please let know how to detect a `nan` value for the `tStatistic` variable please (so I can act accordingly).

I have tried to identity if the resulting tStatistic is a number using:

```
if isinstance(tStatistic , Number) :
    do something
else:
    do something else
```

but unfortunately I can't get this to work.

Comment: `math.isnan(tStatistic)`

Comment: or in if you've imported `pandas` already, `pd.isnull` will work, but keep in mind, it will also identify `None` as "null". So, it returns `True` for either `None` or `NaN`